# HTML anchoring PHP echo values

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to anchor an echo value. My code is as follows;

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo $row(['links'];

}
```

I would like to anchor the value of echo $row['links'] in HTML.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

  echo "<a href='".$row['links']."'>some link name</a>";

}
```

but the question was a little unclear

Comment: almost the same rep, almost same first name, beat me by 35 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

you mean?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo "<a href='" . $row['links'] . "'> text here </a>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
<li><p class="links">
<?php echo($row['links']); ?>
</p></li>
<?php end_while; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis.

It should be: `echo $row(['links']);`